# asp.net page authentication security level

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am currently using:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A") //If the logged in user is not Admin
    {
        //disable the following images and links
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        GridView2.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

to block visibility of certain items on a webpage to those who do not have admin privileges.

My questions is: how can I rewrite this code so that it blocks visibility to anyone who is not an Admin OR logged in as a User (these being the 2 security levels my site uses)?

I have tried writing `if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A" || "U")` to use an OR operator but this will not compile.

does anyone know an easy was I can rewrite this to say `if != admin or user`

or potentially `if = unauthenticated`

I have done some searches and most point to setting the authentication mode to forms and adding an authorize class to the controller or something like that but I really only need this authentication for one page on my site

asp.net website  in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write `if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A" || "U")`

as

```
if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A" || Session["SecurityLevel"] != "U")
```

but you may want to use an `&&` condition

```
 if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A" && Session["SecurityLevel"] != "U")
```

Comment: thanks! 
if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A" && Session["SecurityLevel"] != "U")
 worked great.